# Thread Safety for Parallel Tasks in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

Are the internals of a delegate to the Task Parallel Library thread safe - i.e. is that value of a variable declared within that delegate isolated to that thread?

Example:

```
Parallel.ForEach(collection, item => {
    var something = new Something(item.Property);
});
```

Is `something` guaranteed to always be a unique to a thread, protected against being overwritten by another thread created by the same `Parallel` operation?

Comment: As detailed below, this example is thread-safe. But that is not always/automatically  the case when using the TPL. Making sure that Tasks are independent or otherwise thread-safe remains the main responsibility of the programmer. No compiler warnings, no tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a delegate `something` is a local variable and certainly thread-safe if it is of a *value type* - of course it can still be overwritten if the variable holds a *reference* to a shared reference object (e.g. a reference to a variable that the delegate uses as a closure)

Comment: So if `collection` has 10 items, and the TPL spawns 10 threads, it's possible that all 10 threads are addressing the same reference to `something`?

Comment: Only if the collection has 10 identical references in it.  Presumably, the collection would have unique objects for each entry.  If the collection has the same object added to it multiple times then you could potentially have "something" reference the same object in memory.

Comment: @lukiffer: If your example is really what you are doing in the delegate then no, each thread will hold a separate reference to a new `Something` object

Comment: This bit me recently when I was using the Parallel library with a BackgroundWorker and a Timer on a large collection of data. Essentially, the BackgroundWorker and Timer allowed multiple instances to spin up, but each worker ended up working on the same collection. Ugly race condition. Silly mistake.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - good point about duplicates in `collection` but reading a property will generally be thread-safe in any case.